# What are the main differences between NOT IN vs. <> ALL?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, execution

I was asking myself whether I should use `<> ALL` or `NOT IN`. Have a look at these two sample queries:

```
SELECT PersonId FROM tabPerson
WHERE PersonId <> ALL(SELECT ParentId FROM tabPerson)
```

---

```
SELECT PersonId FROM tabPerson
WHERE PersonId NOT IN(SELECT ParentId FROM tabPerson)
```

The two queries are returning exactly the same results.

Now I'm wondering what the main differences between `<> ALL` and `NOT IN` are. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: If you want others to understand your query use `NOT IN`

Comment: I'd assume the second short circuits, but the compiler probably recognizes the equivalence.  You can actually run both of these queries in SSMS and view the actual query plan.  Do you not know how to do that?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I know that `<> ALL` isn't as readable as `NOT IN` and I hate unreadable code, however I'd like to know if there is any difference in performance or execution between them.

Comment: Hah, just ran it and the query plans are 100% exactly the same.  So there really isn't a difference, only in readability.  And better readability is always the one to go with.

Comment: I have been using sql server since sql server 6.5 and have never heard of ALL until today. The example in BOL is so contrived that nobody would write a query like that in the real world. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178543.aspx

Comment: @Will So I'll use `NOT IN` if it's just a difference in readability :)

Comment: @diiN_ you need to learn how to examine execution plans. Then you can view how your queries are working. Check out this free e-book. https://www.red-gate.com/library/sql-server-execution-plans-2nd-edition

Comment: @SeanLange I tried it now and got the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both queries will produce exactly the same results. Even if the column queried in the subquery contains NULL values, it will not make any difference.

I compared a couple of execution plans of such queries on tables in my databases here and in each case they also were exactly the same.

So only the only difference is readability/familiarity of the code to other developers. There is a clear advantage for the `NOT IN` expression here. The `ALL` (and equally `ANY` and `SOME`) keyword is rarely used and will feel alien to other developers.

See the MS Technet Article *[Comparison Operators Modified by ANY, SOME, or ALL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187074%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)* for further explanation of these keywords. – BTW: This article concludes with the finding that the both statements from your question are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

This statements are similar:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (a INT)
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES (1), (2)

DECLARE @t2 TABLE (b INT)
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES (2)

SELECT * FROM @t1
WHERE a <> ALL(SELECT b FROM @t2)

SELECT * FROM @t1
WHERE a NOT IN (SELECT b FROM @t2)
```

Even if we talk about issue with `NULL` values:

```
INSERT INTO @t2(b) VALUES (NULL)

SELECT * FROM @t1
WHERE a <> ALL(SELECT b FROM @t2)

SELECT * FROM @t1
WHERE a NOT IN (SELECT b FROM @t2)
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that they return the same results. But I wanted to know if there is a difference in performance or execution.